# Which is the best library of relevant geotagged images?

Tags: image, api, geotagging

I need a library of geotagged images (one that has a public API), that I can use in my location-aware application. What are my options?

Picasaweb is giving me results, but they are from private parties of people. Images like those should be private, not public and I definitely do not want them to show up in my application!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend **Panoramio** for general outdoor images:
http://www.panoramio.com/api/data/api.html

**Flickr** is also good but I think their terms are a bit restrictive on commercial applications:
http://www.flickr.com/services/apps/create/

**Instagram.com** is a lot of fun, but might have the same problem as you mentioned from Picasa